# Threejs Matrix4 Float32Array format bug with Chrome + Firefox

Tags: matrix, three.js

I am facing 2 bugs where I have an THREE.Object3D() with some other objects as children... a basic scene in fact. I am using Three.js R69.

**Bug 1 (with Chrome) :** The bug comes when I `console.log(Object3D.matrix)` I get a good return -> elements have a correct matrix.
The next line, I `console.log(Object3D.matrix.elements)` it returns an array representing an Identity matrix. 
Surprising.

**Bug 2 (with Chome + Firefox) :** Bug 1 doesn"t appear on Firefox. So I continued my work. And everytime I try to use function `Matrix4.clone()`, the function return also an identity. 
I tried to isolate this problem and it seems it comes from the `Matrix4.fromArray` function where 
line 5298 `this.elements.set( array );`
always returns an identity.

Has anyone faced this problem before ? Has anyone got an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: May be you have set elements in the matrix by yourself ? Sounds like having elements in matrix prototype fighting with elements as direct properties of matrix .

Comment: yes you are right. That what it is. Thanks a lot @vals for your help.